# nullptr error in c++ dynamic 2d allocation unique_ptr

Tags: c++, dynamic, 2d, unique-ptr, allocation

This is my code. I want to input random value into unique_ptr 2d allocation.
There is an error named nullptr.
Can you help me?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
typedef unique_ptr<unique_ptr<int[]>[]> uniquePtr;

uniquePtr arr;
srand(time(NULL));
cout << "size: " << endl;
cin >> size;
int max = size * size;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        arr[i][j] = rand() % max;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself: What memory does `arr` point to?

Comment: `arr` is a null pointer, you haven't assigned anything to it

Comment: You should probably have a call to `make_unique` using the value of `size`  ...

Comment: How can I put the value into arr? I understand that dynamic allocation makes spaces for input data.

Comment: *I understand that dynamic allocation makes spaces for input data.* It does, but you didn't do any dynamic allocation.

Comment: Thanks for everyone! I solved this using `make_unique`.

Comment: You can answer your own question if you will take 5 minutes to explain your code changes.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this using `make_unique`.

```
uniquePtr arr = make_unique<unique_ptr<int[]>[]>(size);
```

Comment: You also make to `make_unique` every row of the matrix.